# Canonical Decomposition

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$T_1 =\displaystyle \prod_ { p\leq \sqrt{3n}}{p^x}  $
$ T_2 =\displaystyle \prod_ {  \sqrt{3n} < p \leq 2n}p^x $                        $ T_3 =\displaystyle \prod_ {  2n+1 < p \leq 3n+1}p$ 
where  $3n \choose 2n $ =$T_1T_2T_3$. The proof states that the prime decomposition of $3n \choose 2n$ implies that the powers in $T_2$ is less than $2$ for the prime decomposition of $3n \choose 2n$. Moreover, if we claim that prime $p$ 
satisfies $\frac{3n}{4}<p \leq$ n then its power in $T_2$ is $0$. I am quite confused on how did it happen.It says that Theorem 13 can be use. How did it happen that $T_2$ become $0$ or less than $2$?
[image].

Comment: It follows from $\displaystyle n! = \prod_p p^{\textstyle\sum_{k \ge 1} \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor}$

Comment: @reuns . That is the canonical decomposition of n!. But the given interval their is $ p \leq n $ but $T_2$ interval is $ \sqrt{3n}< p \leq 2n $. How can it be?Can you please elaborate?

Comment: ${n\choose j} = \frac{n!}{j! (n-j)!}$